# Can I find out when applications get killed by android OS?

Tags: android

For instance by registering as a receiver of some intent.
I realize that the OS won't tell my app, and that's fine, I'm not expecting that. I am, however, expecting to be able to register something on the OS level to receive these sorts of broadcasts. They end up in logcat, so presumably they should be something you can subscribe to. Are they?

Comment: register it in AndroidManifest not in code ...

Comment: Fine, but for which thing to I register?

Comment: i didn't understand you ... you wana build app that will watching if OTHER apps get killed? so i duno ...

Comment: No, I mean, for which intent do I register to see if an activity has been killed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is if you have the device firmware signing key. There is a permission, `android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER`, which lets you install a callback to be notified but the permission is only granted if your APK has that signature.

Short of that you could poll the system to see what activities are active but that would be time consuming / battery wasting.

Comment: Yes, and it would require that the thing doing the polling hasn't been killed, in turn.